# "This StoreProduct represents an SK1 product" Revenuecat error about offers showing

Tags: flutter, dart, subscription, revenuecat

I have a flutter app about daily horoscope and tarot cards and I'm trying to implement an subscription plan for it and I choose to use revenuecat for it but I have difficulties to find a beginner document or tutorials because I really don't understand what I have got to do and also I search the internet about the error but I have zero answers for my situation but figured out something and did my purchase function page like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:purchases_flutter/models/offering_wrapper.dart';
import 'package:purchases_flutter/purchases_flutter.dart';

class PurchaseFlutterAPI {
static Future init() async {
await Purchases.setLogLevel(LogLevel.debug);
}

static Future<List<Offering>> fetchOffers() async {
try {
  final offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
  final activeOffering = offerings.current;

  return (activeOffering == null) ? [] : [activeOffering];
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  return [];
}
}
}
```

and I have subscription page like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:horoscope101/subs.dart';

class SubsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SubsPage({super.key});

@override
  State<SubsPage> createState() => _SubsPageState();
    }

class _SubsPageState extends State<SubsPage> {
   @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   appBar: _buildAppBar(),
   body: Column(
    children: [
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            PurchaseFlutterAPI.fetchOffers();
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Text("Get Offers"),
          ))
    ],
  ),
);
  }
 }

AppBar _buildAppBar() {
return AppBar(
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
elevation: 0,
leading: BackButton(
  color: Color(0xFF9932CC),
),
title: Text(
  "Your Future Is At Your Hands",
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Color(0xFF9932CC)),
),
centerTitle: true,
 );
 }
```

and in main.dart I have like this API key and widget initialize:

```
final _configruation =
PurchasesConfiguration("ios_api_key")
  ..observerMode = false;

Future main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

await Purchases.configure(_configruation);
runApp(const MyApp());
 }
```